# Team Tabs with Custom Organization Level App Not Showing Up in MS Teams

Tags: tabs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have a process that uses Microsoft Graph API to create a group, team, channel and tabs. One of the tabs is a Microsoft Planner and another has a custom application that is installed in the app catalog at the organization level. In the Microsoft Teams UI, the team is showing up and the planner tab that I created through the API shows up but the tab with the organization level team app does not show up. If I query the api for the tabs on the teamId / channel id the tab with the custom organization app is listed. So the tab was persisted properly but it still isn't showing up in MS teams. There are no error codes when creating the tab. I get a successful response with a valid tab id when posting to teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/tabs. Any ideas?

Comment: @toddahealth Teams Tabs only supports web pages that are iframable and https. Opening an app inside a tab is not supported right now.

Comment: So that is the case, the page is iframable and https. If we sideload it into a team tab by uploading a manifest it works fine. However, for the version that is deployed to the organization app catalog, if we try to add that to the team tab through the api it never shows up in the MS teams ui. If I query the teams api, the tab shows up in the response but isn't displayed in the UI. A few times the tab has showed up in the UI but I had to click on the tab, go to settings to get it to render the site on the tab. If there is someone at Microsoft that I could demo the behavior too its easy to show

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT or if there is a way to open a support case for this we could go that route as well. This is for a pretty critical project, so we need to get it straightened out asap.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT - Here it is in a manually added sideloaded state.To show that it shows up correctly when added manually or directly from the app catalog gui. The only case where it doesn't show up is when adding through the api. I tried the v1.0 and the beta api.

Comment: @toddaheath- Could you please share the latest request/response?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT  I have made some progress on narrowing down the issue. The tab that I add through the API still doesn't show up automatically. However, if I add another tab of the same application through the MS Teams UI, the hidden tab shows up as soon as they click the Accept / Save button for adding the new tab through the UI along with the new tab. So there must be something that needs to be in the html page that gets displayed when adding a tab to have that auto accepted when adding through the API.

Comment: Is there something that needs to go in this to have it automatically accepted when adding the app to the tab in the api?
```
$(document).ready(function() {
        microsoftTeams.initialize();
        microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler(function(saveEvent) {
          microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
            .
   .
   .
          });
          saveEvent.notifySuccess();
        });

        microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);
      });

      function createTabUrl() {
        return "https://sdfsdf";
      }
```

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Would be easier to setup a support call so I dont share any NDA material here. Should I do that through the Azure portal?

Comment: @toddaheath- Please send it via email to Microsoft Teams developer support alias mentioned in [feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback) page.